# POST request error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express, nodemailer

I am having some trouble using nodemailer to send email. I am sure I have it all set up correctly. Bumped into some posts about depreciated code with the body parser, I tried their solutions...I think I did that right also.

p.s a bit of a node noob here.

Node version: 4.4.5
Express version: 4.13.4
Nodemailer version: 2.4.2

app.js

```
/*Application file */
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express(); //create the Application
var pug = require('pug'); //require pug for templates
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//require modules
var blog = require('./routes/blog');
var pages = require('./routes/pages');
var tutorials = require('./routes/tutorials');
var home = require('./routes/home');
var contact = require('./routes/contact');
var port = 4000;

app.set('view-engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/templates');

 //ROUTES//
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/', home);
app.use('/pages', pages);
app.use('/blog', blog);
app.use('/tutorials', tutorials);
app.use('/', contact);

 //SERVERS//
//listern on port
app.listen(port, function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        console.log('server is running on port: ' + port);
    },10000)
});
```

contact.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

router.get('/contact', function (req, res) {
    var path = req.path;
    res.locals.path = path;
    res.render('contact.pug');
});

router.post('/contact/send', function (res, req) {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
            pass: 'pass'
        }
    });

    var conName = req.body.name;
    var conEmail = req.body.email;
    var conTopic = req.body.topic;
    var conMessage = req.body.message;
    var text = 'New Mail. Name: ' + conName + ' Email: ' + conEmail + ' Topic: ' + conTopic+ ' Message: ' + conMessage;
    var html = '<p>New Mail.</p><ul><li>Name: ' + conName + '</li><li>Email: ' + conEmail + '</li><li>Topic: ' + conTopic + '</li><li>Message: ' + conMessage + '</li></ul>';

    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'No one <noone@email.com',
        to: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Website Submission',
        text: text,
        html: html
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.redirect('/');
        } else {
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

contact.pug

```
extends ./home-layout.pug
block content
    div.section
        div.container
            div.row.content-container
                div.col.s12.center.heading
                    h4 Contact
                    br
                div.row
                  form(method="post", action="contact/send").col.s12
                    div.row
                        div.input-field.col.s6.form-padding
                            input.validate(name="name", type='text')
                        div.input-field.col.s6.form-padding
                            input#last_name.validate(placeholder='Email', name="email", type='email')
                    div.row
                      div.input-field.col.s6.form-padding
                        input#input_text(placeholder='Topic',type='text', name="topic", length='10')
                    div.row
                      div.input-field.col.s12.form-padding
                        textarea#textarea1.materialize-textarea(placeholder='Message', name="message", length='120')
                    a
                        button(type="submit").waves-effect.waves-light.btn Send
```

Comment: Is this the line where you are getting error  var conName = req.body.name;?

Comment: did you closed the form tag?

Comment: @Dnyanesh It is associated with that variable.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I am using pug (formally jade) instead of html, no need to close tags.

Comment: I thought that may be line where u r getting the error. Is it the same line? If yes then I think you are sending bad request. Please check the object before reading any property. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you would want to make the path you are posting to absolute.

This:

```
form(method="post", action="contact/send").col.s12
```

Should be:

```
form(method="post", action="/contact/send").col.s12
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoops!

```
router.post('/contact/send', function (res, req)
```

should be

```
router.post('/contact/send', function (req, res)
```